# How to save data from an API into a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm getting data from an API and saving into a list called data[].

After this, I'm sending these data to another class to format it.

I want to create a dict, so I can save these data. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import json
import datetime 

class MovieFormatter():
    def format(self, data):
        data = {
            "movie_info_name": data['title']
            "movie_info_duration": data['duration']
            "movie_info_description": data['synopsis']
            "movie_info_genres": data['genres']
            "movie_info_actor": data['cast']
            "movie_info_director": data['director']

            data['trailers'] = data.get('trailers') or []
            "dictionary": [{'url': x['url'], 'type': x['type']} for x in data['images'] + data['trailers']]
        }
        return data
```

Is this the right way to do?

Comment: "Is this the right way to do?" What output / errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `data` object passed to your function is already a dictionary, from the way it has been indexed e.g. `data['title']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
_in_data = ["a","b","c"]
_out_data = ["x","y","z"]
_dict={}


print(_dict)

for i in range (len(_in_data)):
    _dict[_in_data[i]]=_out_data[i]


print(_dict)
```